# money representation in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

How should I work with [Money](http://github.com/collectiveidea/money) with MongoID? Should I configure it as BigDecimal? And at rails level? For ActiveRecord we have something called Money, but AFAIK it just supports AR

Comment: like decimal, int, floats ...

Comment: dm is right. Never use floating point numbers to represent money (like floats, doubles). This will make a lot of butthurt. You will lose cents during representation. For example 10.2 may be represented like 10.19999(9). During rounding and different arithmetic operations you will get increasing error. [Why not to use double to represent currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency/3730040#3730040)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB stores numbers in various [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) data types (int, long int, double).  I recommend you store money as cents (if U.S. currency) and use the long int datatype.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this also.  Unfortunately BigDecimal stores in Mongodb as a string, so it won't let you sum, sort, etc on it like a float or int.

Integer seem to be the way to go storing the value in cents, possibly using the Money gem to abstract it a bit: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

Mongo stores the int using 64 bits on most modern machines I think so there is not much risk of needing a larger amount even in cents.  It looks like you can store between −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 cents, so take off two decimal places to get your min/max value in dollars.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Answer (score 2):

If you like the money gem you can store it as a Money type.

An example: https://gist.github.com/michaelkoper/5007636

It stores the money as an array [cents, currency]

```
class Product
   include Mongoid::Document

  field :price,    type: Money
end

product = Product.new(:price => Money.new(1000, 'EUR'))
product.price.format
# => "€10.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try money-rails as an alternative. https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails It  is pretty well maintained and works with mongoid too!

Comment: I have an issue with it.

I'm currently using:
money-rails v1.12
rails v6
mongoid v7

I would like to set the default currency to be used by each model instance.

I have set the field in my model like below
`field :price, type: Money, with_model_currency: :currency`

But when I try to create or fetch records I get this error
`Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFieldOption`
`message: Invalid option :with_model_currency provided for field :price.`

How do I use the `with_model_currency` option in a rails mongoid application?
How else can I handle money in a rails mongoid application?